# How to get the sum of a mongoose property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to get the sum of schema, using reduce. what the below codes do is not adding the item together but putting them next to each other. For example `20 + 30` should equal to `50` but it gives me `02030`.
any problem with these codes?

```
Tracker.findById(req.params.id).populate("variations").exec(function(err, foundTracker){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        }else{

            const varSum = foundTracker.variations.reduce(function(sum, variation){
              return sum + variation.varAmount;
            }, 0);
            foundTracker.varsum = varSum;
            foundTracker.save(function(err, savedTracker){
```

Tracker and Variation are schema models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are just `concatenating strings` that's why you are not getting correct sum. Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and you will get correct result.

Change this:

```
sum + variation.varAmount
```

to

```
parseInt(sum) + parseInt(variation.varAmount);
```

Comment: sure i will. i have to do it after 8min

Comment: @Sam Ok Great. Happy coding!